# Align small image on a large image as absolute position

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align a small image on top of a big image on a correct co-ordinates.  I believe it is very simple by using CSS but cant able to do on my own.  I created a jsfiddle page for the same.

```
<div style='height:50px'>
    This div height is dynamic
</div>

<div class='imagecontainer'>
    <img src='http://jeema.org/mockimage.png' />
</div>

<div class='iconcontainer'>
    <img src='http://jeema.org/icon-48-mdpi.png' />
</div>

<p class='textcontainer'>Your Custom App</p>
```

CSS

```
.iconcontainer{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.textcontainer{
    position:absolute:
    color:#fffff;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:1;
}
.imagecontainer{
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Malaiselvan/x7db9me3/2/)

I want to place the small image (phonegap icon) and the text exactly like an android app icon in the below empty space.  Can someone please help me on doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your HTML to this:

```
<div style='height:50px'>This div height is dynamic</div>
<div class='imagecontainer'>
    <img src='http://jeema.org/mockimage.png' />
    <div class='iconcontainer'>
        <img src='http://jeema.org/icon-48-mdpi.png' />
    </div>
    <div class='textcontainer'>Your Custom App</div>
</div>
```

and then your CSS to this:

```
.iconcontainer {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    border:1px solid red;
    position:absolute: top:0;
    left:0;
}
.textcontainer {
    position:absolute;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:100;
    top:20px;
    right:20px;
    height:30px;
    width:auto;
}
.imagecontainer {
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:320px;
    height:620px;
    z-index:-1;
}
.imagecontainer img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

**Explanation** 
You need to have an element with `position:relative` in order to have absolute positioned elements on top. [See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/v4rdsqwc/)

Answer (score 0):

Under `position:absolute;`, you just need to add:

```
top: 450px;
left: 40px;
```

and change the numbers until it is in the correct position.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7db9me3/3/)

Note that you should put both containers inside a common container, else your absolute positioning could be problematic:

```
<div style='height:50px'>This div height is dynamic</div>
<div class="uberContainer">
    <div class='imagecontainer'>
        <img src='http://jeema.org/mockimage.png' />
    </div>
    <div class='iconcontainer'>
        <img src='http://jeema.org/icon-48-mdpi.png' />
    </div>
</div>
<p class='textcontainer'>Your Custom App</p>
```

[revised jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7db9me3/4/)

Comment: I appreciate your answer.  But there is a slight problem.  The height of the upper dynamic div can vary.  If I increase the height from 50 to 200 then the absolute position becomes problematic.

Comment: Yes, it will. That is why you need the outer div. Absolute positioning "[will be relative to the next parent element with relative (or absolute) positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)" **I forgot that point: the outer div (uberContainer in above example) must be styled `position:relative;`**. [More Reading](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

Comment: Another idea is to begin from the bottom, and move up -- that is, use relative positioning